# draggable breaking css in vuejs

Tags: html, css, typescript, vue.js, draggable

I am working on a website where usecase is I have to accomodate 3 cards per row and all the cards can be dragged and dropped from one place to another.

Previously I was using this before adding draggable and 3 items were visible per row.

```
<template>
  <div class="container" @scroll="handleScroll">
    <div class="card-container">
      
      <CoursesCard
        v-for="(item, index) in dummyData"
        :key="index"
        :title="item.title"
        :text="item.text"
        :imageSrc="item.imageSrc"
        class="card"
      />
     
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Added to enable scrolling */
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Center the cards horizontally */
  gap: 10px;
  max-width: 1216px; /* Set a max-width for the container */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center the container horizontally */
}
.card {
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 10px);
  max-width: calc(33.33% - 10px);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Include padding and border in card width */
}
</style>
```

Now that i added draggable it has ruined my css and now only 1 card is shown per row and its not my usecase.below is the updated code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container" @scroll="handleScroll">
    <div class="card-container">
      <!-- Loop through the products data and display cards horizontally -->
      <!-- <AddCourseCard /> -->
      <draggable v-model="dummyData" class="drag-area" :options="dragOptions">
        <template v-slot:item="{ element, index }">
          <div class="card">
            <CoursesCard
              :key="index"
              :title="element.title"
              :text="element.text"
              :imageSrc="element.imageSrc"
            />
          </div>
        </template>
      </draggable>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<style scoped>
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Added to enable scrolling */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  max-width: 1216px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card {
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 10px);
  max-width: calc(33.33% - 10px);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
```

How to fix this? Ive been stuck since hours? are there any better alternative to draggable?